# Wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sql-developer, c#

**I am getting Below error message in the catch exception:**

*ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'WS_GET_WEB_TREE_NODES' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored***
***Could not locate Tree Node Security Function List.: The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure.
System.InvalidOperationException: The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure.
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.AssignParameters(DbCommand command, Object[] parameterValues) in e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Database.cs:line 1273
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.OracleDatabase.AssignParameters(DbCommand command, Object[] parameterValues) in e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Oracle\OracleDatabase.cs:line 464
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetStoredProcCommand(String storedProcedureName, Object[] parameterValues) in e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Database.cs:line 1257
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.OracleDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand(String storedProcedureName, Object[] parameterValues) in e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Oracle\OracleDatabase.cs:line 448
at abcBicWcf.Logic.Credentials.CredentialsLogic.GetWebTreeStructure(Int32 employeeID, List`1& treeNodes)
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
Void AssignParameters(System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Object[])*

**C# code:**

```
try
            {
                abcDatabase = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(abcConnectString);
                abcCommand = abcDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand("abc.ws_get_web_tree_nodes", employeeID, null);
                abcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;            

                // run
                reader = abcDatabase.ExecuteReader(abcCommand); 
.
.
}


catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = ResultLogic.Instance.Error("Could not locate Tree Node Security Function List.", ex);
                
            }
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
create or replace procedure ws_get_web_tree_nodes
     (
        p_emp_id      in number,
        p_tree_nodes  out sys_refcursor
     )
  as
  begin
.
.
.
end
```

Let me know if you need any further information to solve this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384101/how-to-get-stored-procedure-output-parameter-in-c-sharp